# Mergers and ultrafilters

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

F - filter over I. 
Please, prove, F ultrafilter <=> when $\forall$
X, Y $\subseteq$ I, if X $\notin$ F, Y $\notin$ F, $\Rightarrow$ X $\cup$ Y $\notin$ F.

Comment: @MariyaSmit: Welcome to MSE! It also helps readability to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards

Comment: How do you define an ultrafilter?

Comment: F - ultrafilter over I, if $\forall$ A $\subseteq$ I, A $\in$ F or I\A $\in$ F

Comment: Suppose first that $\mathscr{F}$ is an ultrafilter on $I$, that $X,Y\subseteq I$, and that $X,Y\notin\mathscr{F}$. Then $I\setminus X,I\setminus Y\in\mathscr{F}$, so $$I\setminus(X\cup Y)=(I\setminus X)\cap(I\setminus Y)\in\mathscr{F}\;,$$ and therefore $$X\cup Y=I\setminus(I\setminus(X\cup Y))\notin\mathscr{F}\;.$$ Conversely, if $\mathscr{F}$ is not an ultrafilter, then there is some $X\subseteq I$ such that $X\notin\mathscr{F}$ and $I\setminus X\notin\mathscr{F}$. But then $X\cup(I\setminus X)=I$, and ... ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $\cal F$ is an ultrafilter, pick $X,Y\notin\cal F$ and use the fact that their complements are in $\cal F$ and it is closed under intersections; in the other direction, if $\cal F$ is not an ultrafilter there is some $X$ such that $X,I\setminus X\notin\cal F$. Use these two sets to contradict the statement you have on the RHS.

Comment: 1)How i can make conversion by I\X ∈ F and I\Y ∈ F   to I\(X ∪ Y) ∈ F.   2)And sorry, can you explain me "in the other direction" a little more detail?

Comment: Use DeMorgan's laws.